# ClickOnce Include local Filepath

Tags: c#

In my ClickOnce Application i am using multiple .docx files marked as content which i am using from my `Directory.GetParent(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName + "\\Documents"` Directory while writing code, but as soon as I publish my Application I have to change the path to `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() + "\\Documents"`, because the application cant find the Path and adds the files to that directory.

Is it possible to use the Path of the Parent of the main directory for ClickOnce Applications?

[Code of the Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpzCx.png)

Comment: Please read this: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/479251)

Comment: If you mark the file as "Build action": "Copy" in their properties, they will be part of output (check /bin/ directory)

Comment: @Pac0, thanks for the suggestion. Now it works, except that I dont have permission to view this file or folder.

Comment: ah, indeed, as it goes to the binary installation folder. Probably you need to make a copy of the docx in a user folder (`%APPDATA%/YourSoft` for instance) folder, and work on this.

Comment: (I mean, when you first start your program once installed)

Comment: Thanks, i will try it out :)